# detecting window close event when opened through window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I am opening a window through `window.open` method. This window is for conducting test. Can i know how to detect the event when user closes the popup window. I want to detect this in popup window only not parent window.I mean kind of ajax request to insert a value in database when user closes it. I have tried `onbeforeunload` but it does not works. Please help me

Comment: you can check it with:  if(window.closed){ //Perform action}

Comment: do i need to add this directly in js file ?can u elaborate a little bit please

Comment: Yes you need to add this in your js. After window.close() you need to check is window is closed or not with this condition : if(window.closed){ //Perform action}

Comment: need to add this in parent window or pop up window ?

Comment: from where you are opening new window(In your case parent window)

Comment: I have implemented it. Its working for me.

Comment: can u show js fiddle please. I am testing it on chrome and if i put window.closed on the parent window then window will refer to parent window . i want to test foe popup window

Comment: Check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/jennifersam/y0jejy8h/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89995/discussion-between-jen-and-singh-rajput-kushagra).

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple try this

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() { 
return 'Are you sure want to logout ?'; 
});

$(window).unload(function() { 
debugger;    // when closing window debugger will hit here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know when a window or tab is closed then use `unload` or `onbeforeunload`, these events are fired too, when you leave the site by a link.

The API for jQuery `unload()`:
https://api.jquery.com/unload/

...and pure javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: This only displays an alert and does not perform any other task